# Disprove that $L_1^*\cup L_2^* = (L_1\cup L_2)^*$.

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages

Disprove that $L_1^*\cup L_2^* = (L_1\cup L_2)^*$.

i.e to find counter example.

I started with $L_1=\{a\}, L_2=\{b\}$ but it didn't worked.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? Your example with $L_1=\{a\}$ and $L_2=\{b\}$ is a counter-example.

Comment: why? it gives same languages. beacause $\cup$ is or

Comment: @Devy: which set includes $ab$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does work: $ab \in \{a, b\}^*$ but $ab \not\in \{a\}^*\cup \{b\}^*$.

Comment: See definition of $\cup$ union

Comment: The string $ab$ is neither in $\{a\}^*$ nor in $\{b\}^*$. Therefore it's not in $\{a\}^* \cup \{b\}^*$.

Answer (score 1):

There is even a counterexample on a one-letter alphabet. For instance, $(a^2)^* \cup (a^3)^* \not= (a^2, a^3)^*$ since $a^5 = a^2a^3 \in (a^2,a^3)^*$.